# session_start() makes site unreachable

Tags: php

Whenever I use the `session_start()` function in a PHP file, my website isn't reachable anymore.

I am currently using XAMMP to work on a project and I really need the session to work. Does anybody have an idea why it's not working? If so please explain it to me! And please ask for any details you may need.

The error I get is:

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESE‌​T

### FIXED - Reinstalled xampp

Comment: Do you have a white screen? An error message from XAMMP? Could you give us the code?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not reachable? Please tell us the exact error message. Would be better if you could take a screenshot.

Comment: Code please... We can't really get the code from your PC magically, can we? :P :D

Comment: also, try to put `ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file, and check if there is some error showing up..

Comment: My file only contains session_start() and the error I get is "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" (Google Chrome error) //EDIT I inserted some html code (just a img tag) to test if it works but still same result

Comment: did you try other browsers ? is your site reachable without session_start() ?

Comment: Without the session_start() it is reachable yes. I tried Internet Explorer aswell but still same result.

Comment: how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///`? Two different animals here. Is your webserver and PHP properly configured also? did you also put the semi-colon for it? `session_start();`.

Comment: @singebatteur "Whenever I use the session_start() function in a PHP file, my website isn't reachable anymore."

Comment: Ofcourse I put a semi-colon behind it. LOL I am accessing it via localhost (xampp). What do you mean by "properly configured"?

Comment: @Ivan I saw that, but i saw a lot of questions not clear on this site as well... better double check

Comment: well we don't know that. You're behind your computer, we're not. remember that ;-) my question was a multi-part btw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right but I am not so lazy to forget a semi-colon ;)

Comment: I never said you were. I/we take posted code and comments literally. If you tell us there's a cat out there and we go out and see a BEAR, well... guess whose words we should have trusted ;-)

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, having consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Comment: @RyanVincent please read the comments all your questions are answered. Your test brought up the same result. Which was obvious cause I said that my file ONLY contains `session_start()` and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by completly uninstalling my xampp version and reinstalling the latest one. What I still dont know is why that error appeared in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you write semi-colon after "session_start()"

```
session_start();
```